# Apache Netbeans 12.0 with jdk 12

Tags: java, glassfish, netbeans-12

I need to run Apache NetBeans 12.0 with JDK 12. But there is this error:

> Glass Fish Server could not be started with jdk 12. Please select another SE platform

How to resolve this error?

Comment: What version of Glassfish are you trying to run?

Comment: Please accept an answer if it helped solve the problem. To do that, click the 'tick' mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

go to Tools>>>Servers>>>Add server>> choose glassfish>> browse where you just download the glassfish and install.

in case it still doesn't work for you. I suggest that you download another version of JDK.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to run a version of Glassfish that doesn't support Java 11 and later.  According the sources I found, Glassfish 6.1.0 or later is needed for Java 11, and Glassfish 6.2.0 or later is needed for Java 17.

<sup>I suspect (but don't know!) that Glassfish 6.1.0 will work with Java 12.  Changes in Java 16 finally closed off access to most of the Java private / internal APIs, and that could well be what necessitated the Glassfish 6.2.0 releases.</sup>

However ...

Java 12 is end-of-life.  It was end-of-life as soon as Java 13 was released.  That was in September 2019.

So my advice would be to either upgrade to Java 17 (LTS) or downgrade to Java 11 (LTS) ... and use compatible versions of NetBeans and Glassfish.

NetBeans 12.6 is advisable for Java 17 support.  (The feature list says that NetBeans 12.5 has "experimental support" for Java 17.)

---

> How to resolve this error?

Make sure that you are using compatible versions of Java, Netbeans and Glassfish.